# How to preserve list structure when appending based on condition in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, append

If I have a list of lists (where each respective list is 1D but of varying length), created for example via:

```
l1 = np.ones(10)
l2 = 10*np.ones(9)
l3 = 9*np.ones(9)
l4 = 2*np.ones(1034)
l5 = np.array([1, 2, 8, 1350, 1, 14, 13, 1467416, 1413, 135, 1, 3 , 9, 8, 9, 10])

l6 = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]
```

and then I want to append only the items in each *respective* list that satisfy a certain condition (e.g. only take values above 9), then I can do this to get the individual values out from the list l6 as a whole:

```
l_count = []

for i in l6:
    for j in i:
        if j > 9:
            l_count.append(j)
```

I would then expect to append every value in l2 and elements 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 15 to the 'l_count' list, resulting in a total of 16 items in 'l_count'.

However, if I want to know where these values came from (i.e. know that the first 10 items came from l2 and the remaining 6 from l5), is there a way to do this in Python? The ideal scenario would be for l_count to have a similar list shape to l6 (5 by 1), with the entries 0 in indices 0, 2 and 3 and populate indices 1 and 4 with the relevant values as shown above. Thank you very much for any help provided

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're trying to get -- would `l_count = [[j for j in i if j > 9] for i in l6]` work?

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I wanted as the output - thanks so much!!

Comment: Would there be a way to get the corresponding indices for these values out as well?


I thought l_count_idx = [[enumerate(j for j in i if j > 9)] for i in l6] might work but I'm just left with 5 enumerate objects that I'm not able to access the values of

Comment: Nvm, think I managed to do it with:

l_count = [[j for idx, j in enumerate(i) if j > 9] for i in l6] and 
l_count_idx = [[idx for idx, j in enumerate(i) if j > 9] for i in l6]

which gets them separately :)

Comment: probably easier to get them as tuples in the same list: `[[(idx, j) for idx, j in enumerate(i) if j > 9] for i in l6]`